# Adding data from two different sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know this question has been asked a lot but I have not found a reference that works for my specific data yet.

**I have two sheets, each with a totals cell. I want a third sheet that will add together the totals from each sheet.**

I am a novice so please be as detailed as possible, I won't be offended if you speak to me like a child, it will probably help.

Comment: What questions have you seen on this site? Why don't they work?

Answer (score 2):

In your third sheet goto a cell and type **=** Then navigate to your first cell click type **+** navigate to the other sheet and cell and click.

Final formula should be something like

> =sheet1!A1+sheet2!A2